# ionic 4 label display issue

Tags: templates, ionic-framework, label

i have problem with labels on Ionic v4.
When i look at the screenshot, you will see the weird look.

But my code just copied from Ionic docs.
Here my code

```
[![<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar color="primary">
    <ion-title>
      Titel
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Default</ion-label>
      <ion-input></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label position="fixed">Fixed</ion-label>
      <ion-input></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label position="floating">Floating</ion-label>
      <ion-input></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label position="stacked">Stacked</ion-label>
      <ion-input></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>]
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTNan.png)

Answer (score 4):

You can try with removing the  tag because in their official website they didn't used  tag to wrap the  elements.So You can try like that -

```html
<!-- Inputs with labels -->
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Default Label</ion-label>
  <ion-input></ion-input>
</ion-item>

<ion-item>
  <ion-label position="floating">Floating Label</ion-label>
  <ion-input></ion-input>
</ion-item>

<ion-item>
  <ion-label position="fixed">Fixed Label</ion-label>
  <ion-input></ion-input>
</ion-item>

<ion-item>
  <ion-label position="stacked">Stacked Label</ion-label>
  <ion-input></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: sry but this is not working, same problem here. but i think i found the solution: app is still running with 4.0.0-beta.1, i will try update to 4.0.0-beta.18.

Comment: This question is for ionic 4 not 3

Comment: Your solution worked for me. Had a similar problem because because my ion-items were inside a grid.